# Sorting Algorithm Hashing and Linked Lists

Tags: list, sorting, linked-list, hashtable

In class we're discussing sorting algorithms, and I understand most of it except for 2 of these questions I got on my homework:

> Explain how you could use hashing with chaining multiple times to sort a list of integers. How long would this take?

I'm kind of confused on this one. How do you sort with a hash table with chaining? I understand how each index of the hash table has a linked list on the side for any collisions in that case. So, would each of the duplicates of certain numbers be stored in the linked list while the others somehow go in order in the hash table?

> What are the advantages of using linked list over array, for sorting, if the nodes were large in size?

I'm just not sure where to start on this one. How does the size of the node affect whether using a linked list would be better than an array?

Comment: I dont understand the first question either, but the second question is obvious: If you use an array, you have to move the real data, otoh using a linked list, you just swap pointers.

Comment: For the first, look up Radix Sort and imagine a way you can implement it with a hash table.  For the second, think really big.  If the nodes are 1 megabyte each and you have a million of them, why would re-ordering a linked list of these monsters be fast compared to re-ordering an array?